# iOS 15 Safari WebRTC voice Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, mobile-safari, ios15

While making a video or audio call using WebRTC voice is coming too low, this issue is start happening after updating the IOS 15. Before updating the IOS version voice was used to coming through loudspeaker but now it don't. I have tried many examples online everywhere this issue is present you can check on given link below

https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videocalltest.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The low volume audio issue is being tracked as a webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230902
It has been assigned to an Apple engineer - but I'm thinking the more comments are added on that webkit bug the more noticeable it will get.